# Character to number conversion error in trigger

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, triggers, to-char

How will the trigger insert between two timings? Getting `character to number conversion` error in the `if` condition while inserting. Below is my trigger.

```
create or replace trigger TRI_INSERT
  after insert on stud_details  
  referencing old as old new as new
  for each row
declare
        strTime varchar2(20) := :new.time_stamp;   -- (eg: '02/08/2013 11:09:42 PM')
  begin
        if (to_char(strTime, 'hh24:mi:ss') between '22:00:00' and '23:59:59') then
             insert into stud_clas_details
              (id,
               v-id,
               w-id,
               al_id,
               time,
               Time_Stamp)
             values
               (seq_ve_id.nextval,
                :new.vehicle_id,
                 :new.way_id,
                 'xxxx',
                 strTime,
                 sysdate);
         end if;
 end TRI_INSERT;
```

Comment: What is the type of `stud_details.time_stamp`? And if it is a some variant of `char` or `varchar`, **why**?

Comment: stud_details.time_stamp is timestamp datatype.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot `to_char()`  a varchar2 with a date format and expect it to work.

instead you should do

```
    if (to_char(:new.time_stamp, 'hh24:mi:ss') between '22:00:00' and '23:59:59') then
```

also if you want to insert the time into the table in a specific format, use

```
to_char(:new.time_stamp, 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

as with

```
strTime varchar2(20) := :new.time_stamp;
```

you will just be inserting the date in whatever the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT is for that session (which may vary per session).

Comment: That all assumes that the `time_stamp` column for the `stud_details` has type `timestamp` or `date`. Given the name, one would hope so, but given the PL/SQL above, best to check first.

Comment: I want to insert the data, only if the :new_time_stamp has the timing in between 22:00 and 23:59.

Comment: @VasuSambandham yes, the if check does that (a char comparison, but its safe to do in this case)

Answer (score 1):

How about instead using:

```
if extract(hour from :new.time_stamp) in (22,23) then ...
```

Comment: Nice. So often I forget about the date and time specific functions. But it is often clearer and more likely to be correct to use the built in functions instead of taking pieces out through `to_char` and working with those.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in the if condition.. Now its working fine.. Thanks for all.

create or replace trigger TRI_INSERT

```
  after insert on stud_details  

  referencing old as old new as new

  for each row
```

declare

```
    strTime varchar2(20) := :new.time_stamp;   -- (eg: '02/08/2013 11:09:42 PM')
    strFromTime varchar2(20):= '22:00:00'
    strToTime varchar2(20):= '23:59:59'
```

begin

```
    if ((to_char(strTime, 'hh24:mi:ss') > strFromTime) and (to_char(strTime,           
         'hh24:mi:ss') < strToTime)) then
         insert into stud_clas_details
          (id,
           v-id,
           w-id,
           al_id,
           time,
           Time_Stamp)
         values
           (seq_ve_id.nextval,
            :new.vehicle_id,
             :new.way_id,
             'xxxx',
             strTime,
             sysdate);
     end if;
```

end TRI_INSERT;